# mariabackup 10.11.3-MariaDB incremental backup taking long time due to "Waiting for log copy thread to read lsn"

Tags: performance, mariadb

The incremental backups on my MariaDB instance are taking long time due to the following:

> Waiting for log copy thread to read lsn 11214585412"

...which takes 3 minutes.

Everything else is blazing fast. If I restart MariaDB then the incremental backups are fast.

I suspect that the long wait time is related to the binlog filesize `pm-bin.0000X`.

Any ideas how I can keep mariabackup fast without restarting the MariaDB instance?

#### Environment

mariabackup based on MariaDB server 10.11.3-MariaDB debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) on DEBIAN 12

#### Command

```
mariabackup --backup --extra-lsndir=... --incremental-basedir=.... --stream=xbstream
```

#### Log Output (excerpt)

> ```
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:11:38 Connecting to MariaDB server host
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:11:43 Finished backing up non-InnoDB tables and files
> [01] 2023-10-05 18:11:43 Streaming /var/lib/mysql//aria_log_control to <STDOUT>
> [01] 2023-10-05 18:11:43         ...done
> [01] 2023-10-05 18:11:43 Streaming /var/lib/mysql//aria_log.00000001 to <STDOUT>
> [01] 2023-10-05 18:11:43         ...done
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:11:43 Waiting for log copy thread to read lsn 11214585412
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:14:35 Streaming xtrabackup_binlog_info
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:14:35         ...done
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:14:35 Executing FLUSH NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG ENGINE LOGS...
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:14:35 mariabackup: The latest check point (for incremental): '10845015067'
> mariabackup: Stopping log copying thread.
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:14:35 Executing BACKUP STAGE END
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:14:35 All tables unlocked
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:14:35 Backup created in directory '/home/cebert/xtrabackup_backupfiles/'
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:14:35 MySQL binlog position: filename 'pm-bin.000012', position '440233284', GTID of the last change '0-8333-1236501'
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:14:35 Streaming backup-my.cnf
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:14:35         ...done
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:14:35 Streaming xtrabackup_info
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:14:35         ...done
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:14:35 Redo log (from LSN 10845015067 to 11214589787) was copied.
> [00] 2023-10-05 18:14:35 completed OK!
> ```

#### MariaDB Configuration

```
[mariadb]
group_concat_max_len=65000

#default setting ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is removed
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

max_allowed_packet=16M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G
innodb_log_file_size=1G

performance_schema=on
server_id=8333
log_bin
max_binlog_size=1G
log-basename=pm
binlog-format=mixed
expire_logs_days=14

slow_query_log
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time=0.5

log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=32M
```